# Ruby: getting a hash of file names and directories

Tags: ruby, arrays, search, hashmap

I'm writing a small Ruby program to list directory differences between two folder locations.

I'm using `Dir["path"]`, which returns an array. I'm iterating over that array to put it into a hash map to make it more searchable, which works ok.

I was just curious if:

1. There is a better function I should be using to get this hashmap, or
2. If there is a native way to get a hashmap from an array.

Edit: I looked around a bit on SO and found people offering the suggestion of using a Set instead.  I'll go with that for now instead of the hashmap.

Comment: Please link to the other questions in an answer here.

Comment: Re: using a set instead of a hashmap - FYI, a Set is implemented using a Hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps your cause. Seems like this operation could be successively nested.

```
ary=[["x", [1,2,3]],["y", [4,5,6]],["z",[7,8,9]]]
Hash[ary]
#=> {"x"=>[1,2,3], "y" => [4,5,6], "z" => [7,8,9]}
```